# Why does rxjs 6 combineLatest have type error when upgrading from rxjs 5?

Tags: typescript, rxjs, combinelatest

I have the following code which compiled without errors in rxjs 5:

```
a$ = Observable.combineLatest([x$, y$])
  .subscribe(([x, y]:[X, Y]) => {
```

When I update to rxjs 6 the following error occurs:

```
Argument of type '([x, y]: [X, Y]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Y[]) => void'.
  Types of parameters '__0' and 'value' are incompatible.
Type 'Y[]' is not assignable to type '[X, Y]'.
  Property '0' is missing in type 'Y[]'.
```

Also, the error goes away if I change either type X or Y to the any type.

Comment: AFAICT, if you pass an array to `combineLatest` it's treated as an `ObservableInput`, so an error is appropriate. Try `Observable.combineLatest(...[x$, y$]))` - but the type inference will depend upon your TypeScript version.

Comment: Thanks for noting that it was an array. Your suggestion seems to have the same error but changing it to `Observable.combineLatest(x$, y$)` solved the error.

Comment: Yeah, the array is unnecessary.

Comment: Indeed I was updating from TypeScript 2 to 3 at the same time so perhaps the rxjs version was red herring here.